# How to check if an Android device is Bluetooth 4.2 capable?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to explicitly use the new secure pairing feature available in Bluetooth 4.2 on Android.

I know I can use `PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE` to determine if a device supports Bluetooth Smart at all. Is there a way do find out if the device supports 4.2?

I am aware that 4.2 is backwards compatible, but I need to do some special steps if 4.2 is supported.

Comment: I will also start programming Android, which uses Bluetooth 4.2 technology. Is there a special book or any other resource, which focuses on specifically on this topic?